# How can I read a text file after a certain posicion in c#

Tags: c#, file, text

I want to read a text file, but I only how to read it from the first character.

Let's say I want to read the text file from the 15th character onwards and not from the beginning.

I'm trying to copy text from one file to another at intervals of fifteen characters each time a button is pressed and this is my biggest problem

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take a moment to read this *carefully*: [Ask]

Comment: Do you know/control encoding of the file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need a global variable and than just use the global variable to add 15 on each event thats triggerd and use substring to get the next 15 characters from the string. Use the global variable currentIndex which you increase by 15 each time.

```
class test
{
    int currentIndex = 0;

    private string myMethod(string input)
    {
        string val = input.Substring(currentIndex, 15);
        currentIndex+=15;
        return val;
    }
}
```